# Why is an error being generated when a character that must be accepted is inputted?

Tags: java, regex, input

I am using regular expressions in Java to check the input of a password field. The following is the code for checking the password:

```
final Pattern check = Pattern.compile( "^[a-z0-9A-Z!$%*()-_[]{};:@#<>,./?\\|]+$");

if (!check.matcher(password).matches()) {
    errors.put("password", "Invalid input");
}
```

When i submit an input containing symbols, for example %, the following exception is being generated:

> exception
>
> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near
>   index 37 ^[a-z0-9A-Z!$%*()-_[]{};:@#<>,./?\|]+$
>                                        ^

I've already used other regex expressions in this same code and they work fine... Only this part is giving me trouble.

Does any of you maybe know the cause for this error?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your character class has two problems:

- you don't escape the `]` in it,
- the `-` placement makes it ambiguous.

What's more, Java also requires that you escape the `[` (other regex engines won't require that):

You should write it a such:

```
final Pattern check = Pattern.compile("^[-a-z0-9A-Z!$%*()_\\[\\]{};:@#<>,./?\\\\|]+$");
```

Comment: The `]` is logical, otherwise where does the regex engin know where the character class ends? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should escape some of those characters? At least the brackets, as you are using them to start your character class.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is due to the copying, but the regex misses some backslashes:

```
^[a-z0-9A-Z\\!\\$%\\*\\(\\)\\-_\\[\\]\\{\\};:@#<>,\\./\\?\\|]+$
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: No. In a character class, the only characters which need to be escaped are the closing `]` and the backslash.